# AS3 printing a 792 x 612 moviclip to a 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper

Tags: actionscript-3, printing

This should really be simple, but it's not.

I have a movieclip that is 792 x 612 pixels on the stage. The stage size is 792 x 612 also. This is embedded into an HTML page.

Below is a screenshot. The red border has been added to show where the 792 x 612 edge of the movieclip is. In reality, the red border is white and would not be visible. 
[image]

I am trying to print it to an 8.5 x 11 piece of paper.

My print function looks like this (it fires as soon as the page loads):

```
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
if (printJob.start()) {
    printCert_mc.width = 792;
    printCert_mc.height = 612;
    printCert_mc.rotation = -90;
    printJob.addPage(printCert_mc);
    printJob.send();
}
```

I should be that simple, should it not? Rotate the clip -90 degrees counter-clockwise and print.

However, the problem is that it is cutting off the rotated movieClip's left and top edges. These are the edges that in the movieClip's normal orientation before being rotated would be the top and right side.

This is an accurate depiction of what is being printed. The grey borders of the image below represent the edges of the paper:

[image]

I am stumped.

I tried adding: `printCert_mc.scaleY = printCert_mc.scaleX;`

and also:

```
printCert_mc.x = (printJob.pageWidth-printCert_mc.width) / 2;
printCert_mc.y = ((printJob.pageHeight-printCert_mc.height) / 2);
```

Adding them just complicated the process and had undesired effects, again with part of the image not being printed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is what got it to work:

```
if (printJob.start()) {
    printCert_mc.width =  printJob.pageHeight;
    printCert_mc.height = printJob.pageWidth;
    printCert_mc.rotation = 90;
    printJob.addPage(printCert_mc);
    printJob.send();
}
```

Originally I had tried:

```
printCert_mc.width =  printJob.pageWidth;
printCert_mc.height = printJob.pageHeight;
```

But since the movie clip is being rotated, i needed the movieClip's width to match the page height, and height to match the page width.